# why we can't use methods of Character class by using object of Character class?

Tags: java, class

My question is why we can't use method of Character class using object of Character class?

```
Character c=new Character('9');
c.isDigit();    // this is invalid in java
c.isDigit('9'); // this is invalid in java
Character.isDigit('9'); // this is valid
```

Why is that?

Comment: `c.isDigit();` - *This is invalid in java*; cause it expects a parameter

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)

Comment: The question was closed as "typo", and that is simply not true. The question clearly states that the "not working code" isn't working and asks for an explanation. Thus voting for reopening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the signature of that method is:

```
public static boolean isDigit(char ch)
```

Note the **static** keyword!

That implies that you better call that method on the class directly, not on individual instances.

Of course, it is *possible* to do `c.isDigit('9')` but that simply doesn't make much sense. You are still calling that static method that has **nothing** to do with that specific `c` you *seem* to call it on.

`c.isDigit()` is **not** valid because that method expects a parameter. You can't call it without one!

In other words: the compiler allows you to invoke a *static* method on an instance of a class, but not to omit the *mandatory* argument!

Comment: @AnkurGahtori That is what I wrote. `obj.demo(1)` and `A.demo(1)` are both **possible**, they both do the same, but it is bad practice to use `obj.demo(1)`.